# arrange/arrangement + singular noun

Tags: verbs

I looked up the word "arrange" in some dictionaries to find out how it differs from "place", "locate", "dispose", etc.

According to the dictionaries, it seems that sentences 1 and 2 below I created are correct. I wound like to know whether sentence 3 is correct.

> 1. The drawing shows the arrangement of the room (how the room is arranged).
> 2. The drawing shows the arrangement of the beds in the room (how and where the beds are arranged in the room).
> 3. **The drawing shows the arrangement of the bed in the room (how and where the bed is arranged in the room)**.

Comment: In terms of the word "arrangement" I consider all three to be incorrect or definitely non-idiomatic.

Comment: @SovereignSun Why do you find this use of *arrangement* incorrect or unidiomatic? I can find plenty of uses of all three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t see anything wrong with sentences 1 and 2. For sentence 3, I might say

**The drawing shows the position of the bed in the room.**

In this context, the use of “arrangement” is normally used to mean the relative positions of multiple objects. For example, you can arrange pillows on a sofa, but you don’t “arrange” one sofa in a room. On the other hand, if you are talking about, say, a large waiting room with a number of sofas in it, you could certainly talk about the “arrangement” of the sofas in the room.